# Java graphic interfaces, how to easily make them?

Tags: java, user-interface

I am wanting to make a java program with a gui. I am extremely familiar with Delphi. It has an inbuilt form builder, which is incredible!

I noticed that Eclipse has a build in form designer...is it any good? Should I perhaps use something else? Wondering what the best way to design a form gui in java is. Any recommendations would be appreciated.

If you are familiar with Delphi, I'd love something like how it works, if it's possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GUI Builder in Netbeans is quite impressive. The Netbeans GUI Builder is one of the few GUI building tools that do their job right in my opinion. A [full description is available](http://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) in the Netbeans website with a [good tutorial to start](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/quickstart-gui.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use [Adobe Flex](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex.html). I has a wide variety of GUI components, and interacts with Java quite effectively through `XML`. So, basically, your Java object is sent through `XML` to your GUI end, and you receive data from GUI end as XML, from which you can very easily get the data and convert it to your Java Object.
So, that makes the interaction with your Java application so smooth.

I personally started using it few months back, and I liked it so much. And now that it has become an `Open Source` product, you can easily get it and get your hands dirty on it.

Comment: It seems an overkill solution for me...

Comment: @Kartoch. Can you elaborate a little more? Have you used `Flex`?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Form Builder in NetBeans IDE. Its very easy to use. It is one of the finest ways of designing JAVA UI. You can also visit here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/learn/

Answer (score -1):

I think, that you would first look for which java gui framework you would like to use and then look to see if there are any Ide tool to help you in your design.